# Strange database error in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have two queries:

```
<cfquery name="getChairReview" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT*
FROM eval_reviews
WHERE faculty = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#HTMLEditFormat(trim(arguments.id))#">
AND evalYear = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#HTMLEditFormat(trim(arguments.evalYear))#">
AND levels = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="chair">
</cfquery>

<cfreturn getChairReview>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="getDeanReview" access="public" returntype="query">
<cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfargument name="evalYear" type="numeric" required="yes">
<cfset var getDeanReview = QueryNew("")>


<cfquery name="getDeanReview" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT*
FROM eval_reviews
WHERE faculty = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#HTMLEditFormat(trim(arguments.id))#">
AND evalYear = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#HTMLEditFormat(trim(arguments.evalYear))#">
AND levels = 'dean'
</cfquery>

<cfreturn getDeanReview>
</cffunction>
```

Both of them work fine when evalYear is 2012. If I send in 2011 I get an error on `getDeanReview` that states: **[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Error converting data type varchar to numeric**

The line it gives this error on is the `AND levels = 'dean'` (note: I had taken out the cfqueryparam tag to make sure I didn't goof that up.)

I find this strange because these two queries are almost identical except one has chair as a param and the other dean. (Yes, I could have had one function to do the job...with extra param for level)

I changed `'dean'` to `'chair'` with evalYear still 2011...guess what? It worked. This is quite odd...

levels is a varchar field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to get back a regular result set when you run a similar query directly against your database (in a native client vs. CF)?  You'll have to strip out your queryparams and replace with static values, of course.

Comment: Yes I get a normal result set back from doing it straight in the db.

Comment: What happens when you completely replace the queryparams within your function, in favor of simple SQL evaluation: `faculty = #arguments.id# AND evalYear = #argument.evalYear#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird.

Okay, for grits & shins, try making the second query:
and levels like '%dean%'

Also, try it the way you have it, but remove the line about year and let it select everything regardless of year... see what your output looks like.

Lastly.. I don't think you need to worry about HTMLEditFormat in your value params in cfqueryparam.

Rob

Comment: Turned out that removing faculty where clause revealed that I had mistakenly had the column set to varchar instead of numeric. As soon as I changed id to be varchar/string it worked. Thanks.

I hate when you get an error on a line that isn't actually where the error is!

Comment: Sweet!  Glad I could help.  It's always maddening when stuff like that happens.  In queries, when it does, you have to strip it down to the very basics... take out most of the where clause and add it back in a piece at a time til you figure it out.  Good job!